# Scraping data off of website that uses Javascript using Google Sheets and/or App Script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, web-scraping

I want to collect data about books by searching their titles in WorldCat ( https://search.worldcat.org/ ). For example, if my input was "Remarkable Creatures", I want it to output:

```
Author Name: Tracy Chevalier
Genre: Historical fiction
Publication Date: 2010
Cover Image: https://coverart.oclc.org/ImageWebSvc/oclc/+-+784064419_140.jpg?allowDefault=false&client=WorldcatOrgUI
```

I want the end-result to be in a Google Sheet, so I would prefer if I could use Google Sheets or App Script to get this result, but I am aware that Google Sheets doesn't have a built-in function to import from pages using Javascript, so I'll accept any help I can get. I've looked at a few solutions, but I haven't found one that has worked for me yet; this might just be because I'm pretty new at coding.

I've tried using Google Sheets functions like ImportHTML and ImportXML with no success (due to the javascript functionality, I've learned). I've also looked for AppScript solutions, but I haven't been able to find the appropriate code for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: "I want the end-result to be in a Google Sheet" - If I understand you correctly, you want the author name, genre, publication date and cover image to be column headings, and specific data scraped from worldcat.org to be displayed in rows? Should your subsequent searches just append new rows to your Google Sheets document, or should they replace what was already there? When should the search be triggered - on `keypress`, or after you've filled in a cell with what you're searching for? Also, what should be done if there's more than one result?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a machine/data interface rather than their website. They offer a REST API. So, you would want to make REST calls, not web scrape.

See: https://developer.api.oclc.org/wcv2